# Use mouse coordinates in form only

Tags: c#, forms, mouse, coordinates

I am trying to make it so that my mouse coordinates are within the form instead of the full screen. So the left top corner of my form is basicly 0,0. And regardless where I move the program on my screen this will stay like that.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the MouseMove event:

```
this.MouseMove += TestForm_MouseMove;

private Point mousePosition;
void TestForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.mousePosition = e.Location;
}
```

These coordinates are relative to the Form itself !

Comment: The e.Location gives you the position of the mouse in the screen. He want to have the mouse position taking the form as reference.

Comment: The coordinates in the MouseMove event of the Form are relative to the Form itself and the sender is the Form. Please, do not make false statements. Control.MousePosition is in screen relative coordinates.